# Multiple systems sharing resources on multiple SoC's

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpi, distributed-computing, hpc, robotics

I have some Raspberry Pi's from previous projects/learning and I would like to pool their resources to make a differential drive robot.

Two Pi's would have one camera each for a vision system, one connected to an Arduino to read analog sensors, one for driving motors, and the last pi is the "control" and hosting a user interface (web app).  Nothing really special here! But I would like to be able to share the resources of all the Pi's for improved performance...

My thoughts on sharing resources is one of two approaches:

1) Use distributed memcached as a RAM cluster and run each sub system on one CPU only to avoid data races.

or

2) Use a messaging layer to distribute processing on all CPU.

To avoid a lot of headache, I thought I could use MPI since it does a lot of heaving lifting when it comes to messaging. However I can't seem to find any examples of any robotics projcets using MPI.

It looks like MPI is *simplest* to design when it's for supervised learning, or genomics (same code and large data sets).

In my case, each sub system runs very different code from the other.  But for example, the vision system runs the same code on a stream of hundred/thousand images. So why not use MPI for the vision, and let the "contorl" schedule when its starts / stops.

Then use its output as input for the next system, which also runs the same code, so can be paralleled.

So my question is:

> Is there a reason why MPI is not a common approach for things like
>   this in Robotics? If so, why and what is a good alternative?

There's a CUDA-MPI for GPU's so maybe this approach is not too far fetched?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree, each sub system runs very different code. But for example, the vision runs the same code on an image stream.  So why not use MPI for the vision, and let the "brain" schedule when it starts and stops, and use its output as input for the next system, which also runs the same code, so can be paralleled.  Thoughts?  There's a CUDA-MPI btw and GPU's are ideal for image analysis. But I don't have 5 of those :)

Comment: In terms of performance improvement over the first design in 1)

Comment: I agree! It's a course of action I am excited about, but that doesn't make it the right one